# Editing music title not working in Android Q?

Tags: android, editor, android-10.0

Few days back android Q was released . I have song edit feature which is used to edit song title in  app which was working fine below Android Q. But same code for updating music now is not working .....

```
ContentResolver resolver=getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
mRowsUpdated = resolver.update(uri, mInserts, MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + " LIKE \"" + audioId + "\"", null);
```

This mRowsUpdated is giving zero. When I searched about updates in Android Q I got about scoped storage but I don't think it the reason ..... Since even by turning it off still it is not working in android Q.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is to understand why you use a LIKE condition? 
MediaStore IDs are unique for each record, so you shouldn't use a "Like", but instead:

```
resolver.update(uri, mInserts, MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID + "=" + audioId, null);
```

About the **Scoped Storage**, your app is allowed to update/delete only media that it owns, so that it has created.
If you want overall media access without restrictions to update/delete media created by other apps, then you need to request such permissions to the user via the [ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE), and use the SAF (DocumentFile) API.

That said, in Android Q the MediaStore has a new column [MediaStore.MediaColumns.OWNER_PACKAGE_NAME](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.MediaColumns#OWNER_PACKAGE_NAME), which defines who owns (created) such media, which is the one allowed to operate with the file without requiring any permissions. You are not allowed to update such column value, only the OS can change it. But it can be useful to filter out when files are created by you or other apps, and show a message to the user. 
Also consider that if your app gets uninstalled and re-installed, the field gets cleared, so effectively you loose ownership of anything you created.

The reason you are getting 0 records updated in your update call, is because you are using a composite query (" LIKE \"" + audioId + "\"").
However, if instead you were targeting/updating a single Uri without any conditions, such as:

```
// mediaUri is the actual file Uri, so in the MediaStore format: content://media/external/audio/media/<the media id>
resolver.update(mediaUri, mInserts, null, null);
```

Then when trying to operate with a not-owned file you would get a [RecoverableSecurityException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/RecoverableSecurityException), which you would use to get a system popup to request the media permission from the user. This has the downside that in Android Q only works for single requests, so 1 file at a time, and only in the next Android release (supposedly R), bulk edits/deletes will be allowed.